# Component of angular velocity along an axis inclined at $\theta$

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

If an arbitrary rigid body rotates with angular velocity $\omega_0$ about some axis, can it be said that the body will rotate with an angular velocity $\omega_0 \cos(\theta)$ about an axis which is at an angle of $\theta$ with this axis. If yes, what is the physical significance of such an equation?

Comment: Simultaneous rotation around more than one axis at the same time is impossible (see [Euler's Rotation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem)).

Comment: @DavidH you ever seen an olympic gymnast do that vault and spin thing? Sure looks like they have some multi-axis rotation going on. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decompose an angular velocity into components e.g. express it as:

$$ \vec{\omega_0} = \omega_x \vec{i} + \omega_y \vec{j} + \omega_z \vec{k}$$

and this is is essentially what you're doing by calculating the component along some axis at an angle $\theta$, though obviously you will need the value in two other directions as well. However there is no physical significance to the values of the components. They are just the representation of the angular velocity vector in whatever coordinate system you have chosen and will be different in different coordinate systems.

Comment: I think this question should be approached from spherical coordinates where $\omega_0$ is the $\hat\theta$ component of the velocity, then the angle $\theta$ could be a projection to some new angle along the $\hat\phi$ direction

Comment: You can choose spherical coordinates or indeed any other coordinate system. $\vec{\omega_0}$ doesn't care!

Comment: I know that, I meant it could help you explain it to the people that don't. But it's your answer. +1 anyway